# Getting error when trying to order by in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I have implemented custom paging  in my .NET MVC application as you can see in down below code:

```
var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
int totalRecords = 0;
using (var ctx = new myContext())
{
var v = ctx.zsp_select_allusers().ToList();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir))
{
v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
}
totalRecords = v.Count();
var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
return Json(new { draw=draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = data },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Implemented custom paging works fine but I'm getting an error on this line of code:

```
  v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
```

where it says:

```
the type argument for method Enumerable.OrderBy(... )cannot be inferred
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because that's not how the method works.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx  Read the docs, it takes a Func<T,R> that returns the value by which you sort.

Comment: Not related, but using `.ToList()`is materializing your collection to memory and defeating one of the main purposes of paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the LINQ operators provided by the .NET baked-in libraries, you would need to construct an `Expression<Func<,>>` to pass into either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`.

For building dynamic queries based on strings provided at runtime, you should probably look at a library like [`DynamicLinq`](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions), which [will allow you to sort by a string like `"someColumnName descending"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687214/120955).

Answer (score 1):

As Will mentioned, `OrderBy` takes a `Func<T,R>` for its parameter - assuming that your list of users in `v` (which is a fairly bad variable name, btw), has properties called *name* and *dir*, you could do:

```
v.OrderBy(x => x.name).ThenBy(x => x.dir)
```

Comment: Actually, I think you need to switch between `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` based on the value of `dir`. And the name he has is the name of the column/field he wants to sort by.